# Is it ever safe to reinterpret_cast the address of a variable to the address of a union?

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior, unions, reinterpret-cast

Is the following well-defined (i.e. does not reply on undefined or implementation defined behaviour)?

**header.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

union union_type { 
  char   c; 
  // many member types...
  double d[4]; 
}; 

static_assert(alignof(union_type) != alignof(char));

int func1(char & arg1);
int func2(union_type & arg2);
int func3(void * arg3, bool arg3_is_char);
```

**func1.cpp**

```
int func1(char & arg1) {
  // perform some operation with arg1, might modify it
}
```

**func2.cpp**

```
#include “header.hpp”
int func2(union_type & arg2) {
  return func1(arg2.c);
}
```

**func3.cpp**

```
#include “header.hpp”
int func3(void * arg3, bool arg3_is_a_char) {
  if (arg3_is_a_char && arg3) {

    // does the following cast rely on undefined 
    // or implementation defined behaviour?
    auto * ptr = reinterpret_cast<union_type *>(arg3);

    return func2(*ptr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Empirically, the above code seems to work as expected (regardless of the underlying alignment of the memory pointed to by **arg3**). That is, even when the address pointed to by **arg3** does not have the appropriate alignment.

My concern is that this is relying on underlined behaviour and some future optimisation might make an assumption about what the valid address of **arg2** can be and then use a different address of **union_type::c**

**EDIT:**
For those interested in the background to this question, **union_type** and **void*** represent output parameters from public API which does not expose any STL types. There are then several accessors for the two types which continue to grow and diverge. Being able to cast the **void**** to the **union_type** would have allowed half to the wrappers to be removed.

Comment: Probably not, but a more important question is, is it necessary? that answer is undoubtedly no.

Comment: Thanks M.A. A system I’m working on has a C API which exposes functions with out-parameters of either a union type or a void * and type discriminator. The void* and type only ever refers to types in the union. There is an ever growing and divergent set of accessor wrappers for these outputs. In general the union wrappers are more mature and well tested.

Comment: I would add to the question that one of your limitations is working against a C API. On the C++ size, you don't have to mimic the C code structure. There are alternative like `std::variant`, `std::optional`, `std::any`, `void*` pointers in C++ is usually a code smell.

Comment: That’s a fair point.

Comment: I think in your case, you can resolve the issue with function overloading of `func2` for type `double[4]` and `char`, and `func3` can invoke either based on its second argument. If the void pointer is coming from C code, that is acceptable.

Comment: it depends on how you are calling `func3` which you haven't shown.